# Need 'single' quotation marks

Tags: symbols

I'm new to overleaf and having trouble with something seemingly quite basic . . . having 'single' quotation marks show up in my document.

I am copy and pasting from Microsoft Word.

(I've look at related posts, but i'm still having trouble)

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}       

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\rvec}{\mathrm {\mathbf {r}}} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color, soul}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

'these' don't work

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Thanks

Edit: I tried implementing @Bernard 's code, but didn't have any luck. Here's what I tried:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}   

\newcommand{\rvec}{\mathrm {\mathbf {r}}} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color, soul}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
```

But it is giving me an error message: Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you want them to look like?  Should they turn into ‘ and ’ or do you want them to be uniformly ' in the output? If the latter, then this is a duplicate of [How to make a real apostrophe or single-quote in LaTeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/63345).

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "single quotation mark". E.g., do you mean a "straight" or vertical apostrophe character? Please advise.

Comment: @AlanMunn I just looked at that post. What's up with the use of "red"? And they don't show an example of it working either?

Comment: @Mico a vertical apostrophe character

Comment: @user159324 - You need to load the `textcomp` package for the macro `\textquotesingle`. However, do please take the following piece of advice to heart: in fine typography, there's simply no real convincing justification for using "straight" (vertical) single and double quotation marks, other than in listings of computer code...

Comment: @Mico that did it! And much simpler than other responses i've seen . . . although it does look a little funky: \textquotesingle{this\textquotesingle}      to get 'this'

Answer (score 2):

It seems that either you insert the single quotes from the keyboard (in UTF8 input encoding) or you use the `\textquote` command from `csquotes`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\newcommand{\rvec}{\mathrm {\mathbf {r}}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color, soul}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

’these’ doesn't \textquote{work} without babel and csquotes,

but enter the quotes on keyboard: ‘these’ works

\end{document}
```

Unrelated: needless to load `color` if you load `xcolor`.  Also, with `utf8` encoding, load `soulutf8`, not `soul`. 
[image]

Comment: having trouble with this. Please see my edit to the original post.